# Send records to messaging queue using either of one policy

Tags: java, object-oriented, multithreading, design-patterns, thread-safety

I have bunch of keys (`clientKey`) and values (`processBytes`) that I want to send to our messaging queue by packing them in one byte array. I will make one byte array of all the keys and values which should always be less than 50K and then send to our messaging queue.

For each partition, I have bunch of `dataHolders` so I am iterating those and then sending it to my messaging queue:-

```
private void validateAndSend(final DataPartition partition) {
  final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);

  // sending data via async policy
  final Packet packet = new Packet(partition, new QPolicyAsync());

  DataHolder dataHolder;
  while ((dataHolder = dataHolders.poll()) != null) {
    packet.addAndSendJunked(dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        dataHolder.getProcessBytes());
  }
  packet.close();
}
```

**`Packet` class**: This class packs all the keys and values into one byte array and call corresponding implementation passed in the constructor to send data to queue.

```
public final class Packet implements Closeable {
  private static final int MAX_SIZE = 50000;
  private static final int HEADER_SIZE = 36;

  private final byte dataCenter;
  private final byte recordVersion;
  private final long address;
  private final long addressFrom;
  private final long addressOrigin;
  private final byte partition;
  private final byte replicated;
  private final ByteBuffer itemBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
  private final QueuePolicy policy;
  private int pendingItems = 0;

  public Packet(final DataPartition partition, final QueuePolicy policy) {
    this.partition = (byte) partition.getPartition();
    this.policy = policy;
    this.dataCenter = Utils.LOCATION.get().datacenter();
    this.recordVersion = 1;
    this.replicated = 0;
    final long packedAddress = new Data().packAddress();
    this.address = packedAddress;
    this.addressFrom = 0L;
    this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
  }

  private void addHeader(final ByteBuffer buffer, final int items) {
    buffer.put(dataCenter).put(recordVersion).putInt(items).putInt(buffer.capacity())
        .putLong(address).putLong(addressFrom).putLong(addressOrigin).put(partition)
        .put(replicated);
  }

  private void sendData() {
    if (itemBuffer.position() == 0) {
      // no data to be sent
      return;
    }
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
    addHeader(buffer, pendingItems);
    buffer.put(itemBuffer);
    // sending data via particular policy
    policy.sendToQueue(address, buffer.array());
    itemBuffer.clear();
    pendingItems = 0;
  }

  public void addAndSendJunked(final byte[] key, final byte[] data) {
    if (key.length > 255) {
      return;
    }
    final byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
    final byte dataLength = (byte) data.length;

    final int additionalSize = dataLength + keyLength + 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
    final int newSize = itemBuffer.position() + additionalSize;
    if (newSize >= (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      sendData();
    }
    if (additionalSize > (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      throw new AppConfigurationException("Size of single item exceeds maximum size");
    }

    final ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    final long timestamp = dataLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();
    // data layout
    itemBuffer.put((byte) 0).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(dataLength)
        .put(data);
    pendingItems++;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if (pendingItems > 0) {
      sendData();
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can send data to my messaging queue in three different ways so for that I created an interface and then having three different implementations:

**`QueuePolicy` interface**:

```
public interface QueuePolicy {
    public boolean sendToQueue(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords);
}
```

**`QPolicyAsync` class**:

```
public class QPolicyAsync implements QueuePolicy {

  @Override
  public boolean sendToQueue(long address, byte[] encodedRecords) {
    return SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueAsync(address, encodedRecords);
  }
}
```

**`QPolicySync` class**:

```
public class QPolicySync implements QueuePolicy {

  @Override
  public boolean sendToQueue(long address, byte[] encodedRecords) {
    return SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueSync(address, encodedRecords);
  }
}
```

**`QPolicySyncWithSocket` class**:

```
public class QPolicySyncWithSocket implements QueuePolicy {
  private final Socket socket;

  public QPolicySyncWithSocket(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean sendToQueue(long address, byte[] encodedRecords) {
    return SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueSync(address, encodedRecords, Optional.of(socket));
  }
}
```

**`SendRecord` class**: This is the actual class which sends data to my messaging queue. It has three different implementations (numbered with 1, 2, 3 as comments) in it and each of those implementations is being called from above `QueuePolicy` implementations:

```
public class SendRecord {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
  private final Cache<Long, PendingMessage> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(1000000)
      .concurrencyLevel(100).build();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final SendRecord INSTANCE = new SendRecord();
  }

  public static SendRecord getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private SendRecord() {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        handleRetry();
      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  // this will retry to send data again if acknowledgment is not received
  // but only for async cases. For sync we don't retry at all
  private void handleRetry() {
    List<PendingMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>(cache.asMap().values());
    for (PendingMessage message : messages) {
      if (message.hasExpired()) {
        if (message.shouldRetry()) {
          message.markResent();
          doSendAsync(message, Optional.<Socket>absent());
        } else {
          cache.invalidate(message.getAddress());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // #1 sends data asynchronously
  public boolean sendToQueueAsync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, true);
    cache.put(address, m);
    return doSendAsync(m, Optional.<Socket>absent());
  }

  // place where we send data on a socket
  private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage message, final Optional<Socket> socket) {
    Optional<Socket> actualSocket = socket;
    if (!actualSocket.isPresent()) {
      SocketState liveSocket = SocketPoolManager.getInstance().getSocket();
      actualSocket = Optional.of(liveSocket.getSocket());
    }

    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(message.getEncodedRecords());
    try {
      return msg.send(actualSocket.get());
    } finally {
      msg.destroy();
    }
  }

  // #2 sends data synchronously without taking socket as a parameter
  public boolean sendToQueueSync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
    return sendToQueueSync(address, encodedRecords, Optional.<Socket>absent());
  }

  // #3 sends data synchronously but by taking socket as a parameter
  public boolean sendToQueueSync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords,
      final Optional<Socket> socket) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, false);
    cache.put(address, m);
    try {
      if (doSendAsync(m, socket)) {
        return m.waitForAck();
      }
    } finally {
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
    return false;
  }

  // called by ResponsePoller thread to tell us that messaging queue
  // has received data
  public void handleAckReceived(final long address) {
    PendingMessage message = cache.getIfPresent(address);
    if (message != null) {
      message.ackReceived();
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }
}
```

I have my code working fine.. The idea is very simple: I am sending data to my messaging queue via either of those three `QueuePolicy` implementations. It depends on how clients want to send data. As of now I am passing implementation of `QueuePolicy` in the `Packet` constructor and then sends data via that policy. Each `QueuePolicy` implementation calls corresponding method in `SendRecord` class.

- Does my `Packet` class needs to know on how data is being sent? I think `Packet` class is just a container, and that's all it is. I think we shouldn't expect it to know how to transmit itself. A transmitter does that.
- Also, each `QueuePolicy` implementation calls corresponding method of `SendRecord` class. Is this really needed or there is any better way? Can we not get rid of `SendRecord` class and have them implemented in each of these three `QueuePolicy` implementations?

I believe with my design, I might be breaking [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) or not following oops standard properly so wanted to see if we can design this efficiently and if there is any better way? What is the best way by which we can send key(s) and value(s) by packing them in one byte array (following that 50K limit) either through sync or async mode?

Comment: What do you mean by "either of one policy"? Can't you only have either of many?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was - I have many policies to choose from and I will pick only one policy to send data on it. I won't mix two or three policies to send same data.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is pretty neat looking but, alas, I think the architecture is wrong.

Packet should be an immutable object acting as a passive container IMO.... by doing this you are removing the following fields :

  `long address;
  long addressFrom;
  long addressOrigin;
  QueuePolicy policy;
  int pendingItems = 0;`

SendRecord have multiple problems, the main one being : it does way too much. The others problems that come to my mind is the fact that it's a singleton (making mocking in your tests a royal pain), and the fact that the constructor is starting an executor... constructor doing too many things is a bad practice for some (me included :)).
I think it's that big because you wanted to have a cache shared between all policies and because you wanted to handle the retries of message in it. If i'm right : you should address the first point with dependency injection in the various `QueuePolicy`s, I'll propose a solution for the other problem a bit below.

Thirdly, I think you should abstract the addresses in an `Address` class, manipulating `long` feels really awkward.
The `Address` objects may be nothing more than a wrapper around a long, but they will be responsible for ensuring that their wrapped value isn't complete cr*p.
Modify the `sendToQueue` accordingly ;)

Then, I'd probably create a PacketSender/PacketWriter interface... making it **Closeable** (I think it suits your use-case) like this :

```
public interface PacketSender extends Closeable {

    Address getAddress();

    void sendRecord(Packet packet) throws IOException;
}
```

With a default `SimplePacketSender` that takes an address and the `QueuePolicy`.

As already said, if you want to use your cache between your differents `QueuePolicy` implementations you may need to inject it through the constructor.

The `SimplePacketSender` class would not retry to send datas by default, it's better to let your users decide whatever they want to retry or not. You could use a parameter for this but I'd rather create a decorator like this :

```
public class PacketSenderThatRetries implements PacketSender {

    private final PacketSender decorated;

    public PacketSenderThatRetries(final PacketSender decorated) {
        this.decorated = Objects.requireNonNull(decorated, "decorated must not be null");
    }

    @Override
    public Address getAddress() {
        return decorated.getAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendRecord(final Packet packet) throws IOException {
        // TODO start a scheduler here and handle retry by calling the decorated method
    }
}
```

In the end, creating a retrying packet sender may look like this :

```
final Cache<Long, PendingMessage> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(1000000)
                .concurrencyLevel(100).build();
Address address = new Data().address();
try (PacketSender ps = new PacketSenderThatRetries(new SimplePacketSender(
          address, new QPolicySync(cache)))) {
    ps.sendRecord(new Packet(partition));
}
```

One last point : some people think it's a bad practice to use `Optional`s as parameter in Java ;)

Hope it helps !

Comment: Yeah I also think architecture should be changed as I might not be following oops standard properly. I got some idea from your suggestion but I am confuse as of now how your approach is gonna fit in my code. If possible, can you provide an example basis on my code so that I can understand better.

Comment: Lots of great suggestions/solutions are given here. If you struggle to see the whole picture, then I would say - write down small logical rules and how they are connected with each other. Ronan suggested list of rules - if you apply all that immediately - you have a broken full picture then. Write down your logical rules and write down what is suggested and instead of doing one big change - do 10-15 iterations, then you will not suffer with this. This approach works for me and helped me a lot.